# Any idea how to solve this equation with summation within logarithm?

Tags: logarithms

This is the equation:
$$A\alpha\,e^{-\alpha t}+B\beta\,e^{-\beta t}=(A+B)\gamma\,e^{-\gamma t}$$
where $A$, $B$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are all known constants.

I would like to solving for $t$, and I don't know how to take care of the L.H.S. after I take logarithm of both sides:
$$ln(A\alpha\,e^{-\alpha t}+B\beta\,e^{-\beta t})=ln[(A+B)\gamma]-\gamma t$$

I am trying to do this before I turn to numerical approximation.

Thanks!

=======================

**EDIT:**

The actual constants are $k_a$, $CL$, $V_1$, $Q$ and $V_2$, which are all individual positive real numbers (for simplicity, I will denote them, respectively, as $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$ and $x_5$), such that

$$\begin{cases}
\beta=\frac{1}{2}[\frac{x_4}{x_3}+\frac{x_4}{x_5}+\frac{x_2}{x_3} - \sqrt{(\frac{x_4}{x_3}+\frac{x_4}{x_5}+\frac{x_2}{x_3})^2-4\frac{x_2x_4}{x_3x_5}}]
\\
\alpha=\frac{1}{\beta}\frac{x_2x_4}{x_3x_5}
\\
B=\frac{x_1(\frac{x_4}{x_5}-\beta)}{x_3(x_1-\beta)(\alpha-\beta)}
\\
A=\frac{x_1(\frac{x_4}{x_5}-\alpha)}{x_3(x_1-\alpha)(\beta-\alpha)}
\\
\gamma=x_1
\end{cases}$$

Therefore, $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ should be positive, while $A$ and $B$ can be positive or negative.

Comment: Numerical methods only, I bet. Are the constants all positive ?

Comment: Some are not. I have supplemented the question.

Comment: Not that it really matters .... for $\beta$ is the leading term (and later) really $\frac{ x_4 }{ x_3 } + \frac{ x_4 }{ x_5 }$ as in $Q( 1/V_1 + 1/V_2)$?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align} 
A\alpha\,\exp(-\alpha t)
+B\beta\,\exp(-\beta t)
&=(A+B)\gamma\,\exp(-\gamma t)
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

Under given conditions equation \eqref{1} 
can be simplified to

\begin{align}
p\,\exp(-u\,t)+q\, \exp(-v\,t)-1&=0
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}
where

\begin{align}
u&=\alpha-\gamma
,\quad
v=\beta-\gamma
,\\
p&=\frac{\alpha A}{\gamma(A+B)}
,\quad
q=\frac{\beta B}{\gamma(A+B)}
.
\end{align}

And expression \eqref{2}
is equivalent to

\begin{align}
p\,x^a+q\,x-1&=0
\tag{3}\label{3}
\\
\text{for }\quad
x&=\exp(-v\,t)
,\\
a&=\frac uv
.
\end{align}

Unfortunately,
equation of the form \eqref{3} 
does not have a closed-form
solution, not even in terms
of the Lambert W function,
unless $a$ happens to be 
a small integer less than $5$.
So, as @Claude Leibovici noted in the comments,
the numerical root finding is the only option in this case.